# JQGRID - Color del texto y fondo de la columna cuando la fila toma el foco

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jqgrid

Uso jquery y jgrid para crear una grilla en php.
He modificado el color de una columna de mi grilla, usando:

```
$grid[“loadComplete”] = "función(id) { onloadFunction(id)";
```

La función onloadFunction es la siguiente:

```
función onloadFunction(ids) {

   var ids = $(“#lstStudents”).jqGrid(‘getDataIDs’);

   para (var z=0;z<ids.longitud;z++) {

      var id=ids[z];

      $(“#lstStudents”).jqGrid(‘setCell’,id, ‘trimestre1’,” {‘background’:’rgb(250, 250, 250)’});
      $(“#lstStudents”).jqGrid(‘setCell’,id, ‘trimestre1’,” {‘color’:’rgb(0, 0, 0)’});

   }
}
```

Al seleccionar una fila, la columna cuyo color modifiqué en la función onLoadFunction, queda con el color establecido, es decir, no toma el color definido de una fila seleccionada. 
¿Cómo haría para que la columna modificada también tenga el color de fondo y el color del texto del resto de las columnas?

Imagen para aclarar mejor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HNKN.jpg

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Para modificar el color de las columnas debes usar `setRowData` ej:

```javascript
gridComplete: function(){
 var rows = $("#lstStudents").getDataIDs(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
   var status = $("#lstStudents").getCell(rows[i],"status");
     if(status == "0"){
     $("#listCtrl").jqGrid('setRowData',rows[i],false, {       
            color:'white',weightfont:'bold',background:'red' });            
      }
    }
}
```

En esta función lo único que he realizado es leer una variable de la grid la cual he llamado status para en base a ella ponerla de color rojo.